# Create ul and li elements for folder and subfolder

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to show directory and subdirectories from my FTP server to looks like this:

```
https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=77.0_1
```

I have done this using PHP function `ftp_list_files_recursive`:

```
/* contents - ftp function */
    function ftp_list_files_recursive($ftp_stream, $path){
        $lines = ftp_rawlist($ftp_stream, $path);

        $result = array();

        foreach ($lines as $line){
            $tokens = explode(" ", $line);
            $name = $tokens[count($tokens) - 1];
            $type = $tokens[0][0];
            $filepath = $path . "/" . $name;

            if ($type == 'd'){
                $result = array_merge($result, ftp_list_files_recursive($ftp_stream, $filepath));
            } else {
                $result[] = $filepath;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /* contents - ftp */
    $contents = ftp_list_files_recursive($conn_id, ".");

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($contents);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Using above function it returns me list of folders, subfolders and files:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Forze.Hotel-Italy.mp4
    [1] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Forze.Hotel-Italy.txt
    [2] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/DSC0586.png
    [3] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/DSC0587.png
    [4] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/DSC0597.png
    [5] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/DSC0598.png
    [6] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/Beths/DSC0600.png
    [7] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/Beths/DSC0601.png
    [8] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/Kitchen/DSC0602.png
    [9] => ./Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy/Hotel01/Rooms/Kitchen/DSC0603.png
    [10] => ./Unsorted.Hotel.Room.[Room-123].png
    [11] => ./Unsorted.Hotel.Bathroom.[Bathroom-124].png
)
```

So it needs to look like this:

```
    Forze.Vacation.2016-Italy
       -> Hotel01
             Forze.Hotel-Italy.mp4
             Forze.Hotel-Italy.txt
             DSC0586.png
             DSC0587.png
             -> Rooms
                DSC0597.png
                DSC0598.png
                -> Beths
                   DSC0600.png
                   DSC0601.png
                   -> Kitchen
                      DSC0602.png
                      DSC0603.png
    Unsorted.Hotel.Room.[Room-123].png
    Unsorted.Hotel.Bathroom.[Bathroom-124].png
```

I try using PHP function to check if folder and subfolder to generate `<ul>` `<li>` and `</ul>` and `</ul>`

```
<div id="treeview-checkbox-demo">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                                $f = -1;
                                $sub = -1;
                                $files = 1;

                                foreach ($result as &$value) {
                                    /* check - subdirectory */
                                    if (strpos($value, 'SUBDIR') !== false) {
                                        $folder = str_replace($folder, '', $value);
                                        $folder = str_replace('SUBDIR.//', '', $folder);
                                        echo '<li>&nbsp;'.$folder;
                                        echo '<ul>';
                                        $sub = 1;
                                        $files++;
                                    }

                                    /* check - folder */
                                    if (strpos($value, 'FOLDER') !== false) {
                                        /* end folder */
                                        if ($f == 0) {
                                            echo '</ul>';
                                            echo '</li>';
                                        }
                                        $folder = explode('./', $value)[1];
                                        echo '<li>&nbsp;'.$folder;
                                        echo '<ul>';
                                        $f = 0;
                                    } else {
                                        if ($sub == 1) {
                                            /* show filename */
                                            $file = explode('./', $value)[$files];
                                            $file = explode('/', $file)[$files+1];
                                            if ($file) {
                                                echo '<li data-value="'.$value.'">&nbsp;'.$file.'</li>';
                                                $f = 0;
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            /* show filename */
                                            $file = explode('./', $value)[$files];
                                            $file = explode('/', $file)[$files];
                                            echo '<li data-value="'.$value.'">&nbsp;'.$file.'</li>';
                                            $f = 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

But it create folder and mismatched subfolders and files inside...and needs to have structure like this:

```
https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=77.0_1
```

I im building admin site for administration for hotels to download/upload files to ftp server, but i im stuck with `<ul>` `<li>` generation of `folders/subfolders/files`

Comment: How is this related to jQuery after all, if the PHP code does already provide stuff you don't want to have? Why not return a properly nested structure instead of a single-dimensional array?

Comment: You are right...i edit post above and change from jQuery to PHP/HTML. Can you give example code how to return nested structure? I im stuck above and don't know how to rewrite code to return as you suggested nested structure code